# Create a query to ignore case? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oracle

I'm looking for a way to create a query through a winform application to query an Oracle database but ignoring the case of the data.  Is this possible to do without having to modify anything in Oracle itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply upper- or lowercase all:

```
SELECT Columns From Table WHERE UPPER(ColName) =  :UpperValue
```

Then use `ToUpper` on the value:

```
yourOracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("UpperValue", value.ToUpper())
```

Comment: or you could always use LOWER as well

Comment: @Randy: That's why i've said "upper- or lowercase".

Comment: i think i chimed in before one of the edits :) anyway +1 from me

Comment: Hi Tim, in my table there's several columns that have both lower and upper in the rows.  For example: 123 N Street Blvd and 123 n street blvd.  When trying some queries out, the LOWER returned a record on the 2nd example but how am I to find the record in the first example? I have tried using UPPER/LOWER before the value but it's not returning a record using that.

Comment: @Criel: As i've shown in my answer, you need to use `UPPER` in the query and `ToUpper` in VB.NET or if you prefer lowercase `LOWER` in the oracle query and `ToLower` in VB.NET. On that way both, the parameter and the values in the table are either completely upper- or lowercase.